# How do I assign inputbox input to variable for each vba excel

Tags: excel, vba, variables, for-loop, inputbox

I have a `for` statement in a VBA script that goes through each cell in a range (number of cells in range is variable based on user input - could be three cells could be 100).  Each instance of the `for` loop calls an input box.  How do I assign the user input from each instance of the for loop to a variable for later use?
Here is the for with the input box:

```
For Each cell In MyQCData
text_string = cell.Value
WrdArray() = split(text_string, ",")
    For i = LBound(WrdArray) To UBound(WrdArray)
        strg = strg & vbNewLine & "Part No. " & i & " - " & WrdArray(i)
    Next i
        InputBox ("This part requires a " & WrdArray(0) & " measurement of the " & _  
        WrdArray(1) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
        & "The range for this is input is " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Lower Control Limit     " _
        & WrdArray(2) & vbNewLine & "Upper Control Limit     " & WrdArray(3))
        Erase WrdArray()
Next cell
```

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of hard to tell without the rest of your code, but I assume that `MyQCData` is a `Range`.  Try the below. I sort of "brute forced" the Inputbox look with `k`, FYI.

```
Dim k As Long
k = 0
Dim inputArr() As Variant
ReDim inputArr(myqcdData.Cells.Count)
For Each cell In MyQCData
    text_string = cell.Value

    WrdArray() = Split(text_string, ",")
    For i = LBound(WrdArray) To UBound(WrdArray)
        strg = strg & vbNewLine & "Part No. " & i & " - " & WrdArray(i)
    Next i
    inputArr(k) = InputBox("This part requires a " & WrdArray(0) & " measurement of the " & _
                           WrdArray(1) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
                           & "The range for this is input is " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Lower Control Limit     " _
                           & WrdArray(2) & vbNewLine & "Upper Control Limit     " & WrdArray(3))
    k = k + 1
    Erase WrdArray()
Next cell

'Check each value in the array. This is optional and can be removed/commented out
For k = LBound(inputArr) To UBound(inputArr)
    Debug.Print inputArr(k)
Next k
```

Edited per @Yow's astute comment

Comment: Tsk, tsk, tsk - `Erase WrdArray()` inside a loop that is using `WrdArray`?  (As far as I can see, the OP doesn't need the `Erase` anyway.)  And do the `Dim inputArr() As Variant` `ReDim inpurArr(myqcdData.Cells.Count)` outside the `For Each Cell` loop or you will wipe everything every time you go to the next `Cell`.  What time is it on Mars - you must be getting tired! :D

Comment: @YowE3K truth time - it was close to Home Time at Wayne Enterprises when I worked on that and may have let one or two things slip my eye. I'll edit when I get home from savi...I mean business dinner.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use an array:

```
Dim inputBoxAnswers() As String
ReDim inputBoxAnswers(1 To MyQCData.Cells.Count)
Dim cellCounter As Long
For Each cell In MyQCData
    text_string = cell.Value
    WrdArray() = split(text_string, ",")

    'Is this loop needed???
    For i = LBound(WrdArray) To UBound(WrdArray)
        strg = strg & vbNewLine & "Part No. " & i & " - " & WrdArray(i)
    Next i

    cellCounter = cellCounter + 1
    inputBoxAnswers(cellCounter) = InputBox("This part requires a " & _
                                   WrdArray(0) & " measurement of the " & _  
                                   WrdArray(1) & _
                                   vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                                   "The range for this is input is " & _
                                   vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                                   "Lower Control Limit     " & WrdArray(2) & _
                                   vbNewLine & _
                                   "Upper Control Limit     " & WrdArray(3))
Next cell
```

---

If your `MyQCData` range is not a single column or a single row, you may find it easier to use a two-dimensional array, which could (perhaps) be dimensioned using

```
Dim inputBoxAnswers() As String
ReDim inputBoxAnswers(1 To MyQCData.Rows.Count, 1 To MyQCData.Columns.Count)
```

but then you will need to rework the indexes to use when assigning the elements their values.  It would **probably** need to be

```
inputBoxAnswers(cell.Row - MyQCData.Row + 1, cell.Column - MyQCData.Column + 1) = ....
```

but a lot depends on how you intend to use the array afterwards.

Comment: I like it. Instead of using a new variable, `cellCounter`, could you maybe do `MyQCData.cell.row`? Or something, the idea being the main range has cells, and use each cells' row *within* the main range?

Comment: @BruceWayne - If `MyQCData` was one-dimensional, you could use `inputBoxAnswers(cell.Row - MyQCData.Row + 1)`, or you could dimension using `ReDim inputBoxAnswers(MyQCData.Row To MyQCData.Row + MyQCData.Rows.Count - 1)` and then use `inputBoxAnswers(cell.Row)`.  (Obviously, if `MyQCData` started on row 1, those expressions simplify a lot because `MyQCData.Row - 1` will be 0.)  So much depends on the shape of `MyQCData` and the intended use of the answers that it is hard to guess what is the **best** way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to dress this in a standalone code that you can easily run to get a feel for what's going on. Array variables must be declared hence `Dim userInput(99)` and the 99 is the upper limit (0-99 = 100 possible values). The first line of the first loop sets the variables, that's `userInput(j) = InputBox("Sample InputBox", "InputBox Title", "blah" & j)` the `"blah" & j` bit is the default entry, which is useful when you're writing/debugging as it's a lot faster to keep *entering* dummy data...

```
Sub inputBoxEg()
    Dim userInput(99)
    Dim MyQCData As Range

    Set MyQCData = Range("A1:A4")

    'Set InputBox inputs to a variable array called userInput:
    j = 0
    For Each cell In MyQCData
        userInput(j) = InputBox("Sample InputBox", "InputBox Title", "blah" & j)
        If userInput(j) = "" Then Exit Sub 'if user pressed cancel or entered blank
        j = j + 1
    Next cell

    'Collate variables collected by InputBoxes in a text string called allInputs:
    allInputs = ""
    For i = 0 To j - 1
        If i = 0 Then
            allInputs = i & ": " & userInput(i)
        Else
            allInputs = allInputs & vbNewLine & i & ": " & userInput(i)
        End If
    Next i

    MsgBox allInputs
End Sub
```

Comment: I haven't had a chance to play with the suggestions here yet, but I can't thank you enough for the responses.  From reading through i see enough that I should be able to get this to go.  I love this site, have learned so much - maybe i'll be answering questions of others some day.  AWESOME!

Comment: Just had an opportunity to play with the suggestions.  PERFECT, THANK YOU!